# GDB Register Display Issue

Tags: math, assembly, printing, gdb, cpu-registers

I have recently started delving deeper into Assembly, and I could not determine what is going on when I analyze the following code segment. Essentially, 0xFFFFFFFF is moved into `EAX` and then 0x10 is added to it. When viewing `EAX` within GDB, the value after execution is 0xF rather than 0x9. When I add 0x11, rather than 0x10, the proper result (0x10) is displayed. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have attached debug output below.

The first value after command execution is `EAX`, which is displayed using `print/x $eax`.

---

```
(gdb) ni
$11 = 0xffffffff
Dump of assembler code from 0x8048096 to 0x80480a0:
=> 0x08048096 <_start+22>:      add    eax,0x10
   0x08048099 <_start+25>:      mov    eax,0x0
   0x0804809e <_start+30>:      add    BYTE PTR ds:0x804910c,0x22
End of assembler dump.

0x08048096 in _start ()

(gdb) ni
$13 = 0xf
Dump of assembler code from 0x8048099 to 0x80480a3:
=> 0x08048099 <_start+25>:      mov    eax,0x0
   0x0804809e <_start+30>:      add    BYTE PTR ds:0x804910c,0x22
End of assembler dump.

0x08048099 in _start ()
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to expect that adding `0x10` to `-1` (`0xFFFFFFFF`) will produce `0x9`.

But `0x10` is `16` (decimal), and adding `-1` to it produces `15` (decimal), which is `0xF`.

So everything is working here just as it should.

Comment: I just realized I was interpreting 0x10 to be A in hex. Thanks for the assistance, you are correct.